# Clarification about pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

```
Object* pObject;
Object object;
pObject = &object;
```

Does `object` and `pObject` gets the same amount of memory allocated?

```
Object* pObject1, pObject2, pObject3;
Object object;
pObject1 = &object;
pObject2 = &object;
pObject3 = &object;
```

And

```
pObject1 = &object;
pObject2 = pObject1;
pObject3 = pObject1;
```

What is the difference between the two?
Is it safe to dereference the `pObject2` and `pObject3` on the second example?

Comment: Pointers have a fixed size (usualy) irrespective of what they point to (pointer to members are different story), because they hold a memory address. So the answer to first question is no. The second block of code is not legal - `pObject2` and `pObject3` are not pointers.

Comment: @jrok ah, syntax error

Answer (score 5):

In the first code snippet, there is only *one* object in memory.
`object` is of type "Object". `pobject` is of type "address of `Object`".

Translating:

```
Object* pObject;    // Objectp is a POINTER that may be used for objects of type Object
Object object;      // Allocate on the stack an "Object". Call it "object"
pObject = &object;  // pObject points (that is, stores the ADDRESS of) object
```

In your second code, there would be three *variables of type "address of something of type `Object`"*, all holding the address of `Object`. Pointers are like "numbers that represent memory addresses". However, as Gorpik menitoned, you should declare them as

```
Object *pObject1, *pObject2, *pObject3;
```

That is one reason it is interetsing to keep the asterisk close to the name -- in this case `pObject` -- and not the type -- in this case `Object`. Read it like "Of type `Object`: what pointer `pObject1` points to, what pointer `pObject2` points to, etc".

The third code snippet has the same effect. All three variabes get the address of `object`.

Answer (score 3):

First, you have a declaration bug. The following line:

```
Object* pObject1, pObject2, pObject3;
```

does not declare three pointers; it declares a pointer (`pObject1`) and two objects (`pObject2` and `pObject3`), the pointer being uninitialised and the objects, default initialised.

Let's assume we fix this bug, such as:

```
Object* pObject1, *pObject2, *pObject3;
```

In the first part, the strict answer to your question is no. A pointer and an object do not generally get allocated the same amount of memory. But I guess you mean if the object occupies the same memory as whatever is pointed by the pointer. In this case, `pObject` points to exactly the memory area occupied by `object`, so the answer is yes. But `pObject` will usually occupy some memory by itself, so it needs more memory altogether (that for the pointer itself and that for the object pointed).

In the second case, both pieces of code are equivalent. `pObject1`, `pObject2` and `pObject3` end up having the same value, which is the memory address of `object`. Dereferencing `pObject2` and `pObject3` is perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1):

A pointer is a variable, that store a memory address

The stored address in the pointer is the address of the first-block of the memory-structure of the object it points at

The syntax of a pointer that points at an object of type `TYPE`:

```
TYPE * pointer; // define a pointer of type TYPE
```

`NULL` (address `0`) denotes a pointer that doesn't point anywhere currently:

```
pointer = 0;
```

To get the memory address of a variable or object:

```
pointer = &object; // pointer now stores the address of object
```

To get the pointed `TYPE` variable, you de-reference the pointer:

```
assert(&(*pointer) == &object); // *pointer ~ object
```

In example:

```
int a = 10; // type int
int * b = &a; // pointer to int
int* * c = &b; // pointer to int*

printf(" %d \n ", a );
printf(" %d \n ", *b );
printf(" %d \n ", **c );

char t [256] = "Not Possible ?";

char * x = t;
char * y = (x + 4); // address arithmetic

printf(" %s \n ", x ); // Not Possible ?
printf(" %s \n ", y ); // Possible ?
```

`void*` is a special pointer-type that can store any pointer of any degree, but cannot be used until you cast it to a compatible type ..

```
void * z = &c; // c holds int**

printf(" %d \n ", **((int**)c) );
```